# Degree of the path $\cos (2 m \pi t)+i \sin (2 m \pi t)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was reading the proof of the fundamental group $\pi\left(S^{1},(1,0)\right)$ being infinite cyclic and it uses the function degree of a path. However, I dont really understand how to obtain it. What would be the degree of the path $h_{m}(t)=\cos (2 m \pi t)+i \sin (2 m \pi t)$

Comment: $m{}{}{}{}{}{}$